# Thumb hover effect not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, hover

I'm tring to build a thumbnail hover effect. It works in every browser, but the IE... Where did I go wrong?!?

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="thumbhover.js"></script>
<script>

$('.sliders li:gt(3)').css('display', 'none');

$(".more").click(function() {
    $('.sliders li:first').insertAfter('.sliders li:last').toggle('clip', 100, function() {
        $('.sliders li:eq(3)').toggle('scale', 100);
    });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thumb img').hoverpulse({
        size: 50,  // number of pixels to pulse element (in each direction)
        speed: 400 // speed of the animation 
    });
});
</script>​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="clients">
    <ul class="sliders" style="font-size: 11px; list-style: none;">
      <li class="slider">
        <div class="left" style="width: 87px;" id="thumb"><img src=
        "images/whit-images/12.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="fishing cancun" /></div>

        <div class="left" style="height: 60px; width: 200px; margin-left: 87px;">
          <strong><br />
          15 min. fight 15 lbs Jack Crevalle</strong><br />
          February 22 2012
        </div><br clear="all" />
      </li>

      <li class="slider">
        <div class="left" style="width: 87px;" id="thumb"><img src=
        "images/whit-images/11.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="fishing cancun" /></div>

        <div class="left" style="height: 60px; width: 190px; margin-left: 87px;">
          <strong>Ben Kirkpatrick with a Baby Tarpon</strong><br />
          February 21 2012
        </div><br clear="all" />
      </li>

      <li class="slider">
        <div class="left" style="width: 87px;" id="thumb"><img src=
        "images/whit-images/10.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="fishing cancun" /></div>

        <div style="height: 60px; width: 200px; margin-left: 87px;">
          <strong>Ben with a nice size lookdown</strong><br />
          February 21 2012
        </div><br clear="all" />
      </li>

      <li class="slider">
        <div class="left" style="width: 87px;" id="thumb"><img src=
        "images/whit-images/9.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="fishing cancun" /></div>

        <div class="left" style="height: 60px; width: 200px; margin-left: 87px;">
          <strong>Cancun</strong><br />
          February 2012
        </div><br clear="all" />
      </li>

      <li class="slider">
        <div class="left" style="width: 87px;" id="thumb"><img src=
        "images/whit-images/8.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="fishing cancun" /></div>

        <div class="left" style="height: 60px; width: 200px; margin-left: 87px;">
          <strong><br />
          Chris Webber</strong><br />
          February 2012
        </div><br clear="all" />
      </li>

      <li class="slider">
        <div class="left" style="width: 87px;" id="thumb"><img src=
        "images/whit-images/7.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="fishing cancun" /></div>

        <div class="left" style="height: 60px; width: 200px; margin-left: 87px;">
          <strong><br />
          Dwayne Perillo, first bonefish of 2012</strong><br />
          February 18 2012
        </div><br clear="all" />
      </li>

      <li class="slider">
        <div class="left" style="width: 87px;" id="thumb"><img src=
        "images/whit-images/6.jpg" width="80" height="60" alt="fishing cancun" /></div>

        <div class="left" style="height: 60px; width: 200px; margin-left: 87px;">
          <strong><br />
          Sweet catch</strong><br />
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider{
    position: relative;
    height: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}   

.clients{
    width: 330px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 320px;
}
```

Here is the actual [website](http://www.cancuntarponfishing.com/), please no comments about how messy the code is. I am not supposed to touch it! (on the bottom half where the clients part is).

Comment: The IE is allways a problem ;-) Which version do you test? Can you put your example to http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just took a look in IE9 and it is being forced to render in [Quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html). Really before trying to work out why IE doesn't work correctly, if possible, spend the time fixing the rendering engine (getting it to run in Standards mode). There's a good chance it'll fix itself.

Comment: Hey Blair, thanks so much.. I read the link you sent, so this basically means that it is not going to work and there is no fix.. correct?

Comment: This was perfect!! All I had to do was change the Doctype to <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">and vaoila! It worked. thank you so much!